# Authenticate request using authkey in geoserver

Tags: authentication, request, key, geoserver

I need to implement authkey module in geoserver to enable clients to send authenticated requests. I followed the [official article](https://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html), and read through the Q&A from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41984/key-authentication-module-geoserver-authkey) and [there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66873/trouble-implementing-key-authentication-in-geoserver), etc. These articles and answers are helpful to part of my work.

As a beginner in geoserver, it took me long time to figure out the complete answer. So I present my solution down in the case that someone has a similar work may benefit from it. In my solution, I used `User property` as the key provider.

It is welcome that if you have better solution, and are willing to share below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before implementing authkey module, I secured the layers by assigning workspaces to different users, give read/write authority to them and also set the Catalog Mode as "HIDE".

The procedure of implementing the authkey is as follows:

1. Download the plugin from http://geoserver.org/download/, choose your GeoServer version, and download the extension.
2. Extract archive to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib (This is the directory for a Linux system).
3. Restart tomcat7
4. Partly follow [official article](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html) using User property as the key provider:

   1). In geoserver Security => Authentication => Authentication Filters,  create authkey filter. Set the "Authentication key to user mapper" as "User property". Select corresponding group. Click "Synchronize user/group service" button.

   2). Modify default filter chain. Remove both basic and anonymous authentication from the chain, attach and keep authkey authentication alone. (This is the [reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66873/trouble-implementing-key-authentication-in-geoserver))
5. Get the UUID from Users/Groups. Now you are able to request from the client with the authkey of the respective user.

Answer (score -1):

thank you for your explanation, but small problem could be fixed authkey value sent from client to server (always same value), so anyone could mimic it?

next better step would be use WebService as 'authentication key to user mapper':

application generates key and adds it to request, application api end point is already fixed in geoserver, and when geoserver communicate with that api to verify, geoserver sends that key back to api and if it is generated by application (valid) then api responds with true geoserver user.
That part of communication would be hidden (secured).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Yes, what you mentioned is a security concern. Maybe we can implement SSL/TLS for the GeoServer to remove that issue. And thanks for sharing an alternative solution.

Comment: yes, I agree, inside of VPN (for example)